# How can I fix this query for records that match BOTH conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a SQL Server newby. I need to filter a query, but not sure how. My query has joins in it, which I have left out here for simplicity.

```
SELECT Name, Date
FROM my_table AS C
WHERE Date = '2019-04-15' AND Date IS NULL
```

My_table has data like this:

```
Name    Date
---------------------
John    2019-04-01
Ally    2019-04-01
Steve   NULL
James   2019-04-15
James   NULL
```

If I run the query for either of the where conditions, I get the results I expect for just one condition. But adding the AND yields no results. Using an OR gives me the last 3 records. But what I am looking for is to filter it down so I would just see the last 2 records, as James has a record that matches the date, and also a record with a NULL date.

How can I filter for names that match BOTH conditions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably you want `OR`, not `AND` : `Date = '2019-04-15' OR Date IS NULL`

Comment: "Using an OR gives me the last 3 records. But what I am looking for is to filter it down so I would just see the last 2 records, as James has a record that matches the date, and also a record with a NULL date."

Comment: So you want only the rows for James? Why don't you filter with WHERE name = 'James'

Comment: ForpasI - t is not always James I am looking for.  I am looking for all Names that have a row with a specific date and a row for the same name wit a NULL date.

Comment: And why did you **not** mention **this** in your question?

Comment: I **did** mention **this** in the question.  "How can I filter for names that match BOTH conditions? " James is the illustrative example.  I am not sure how I could have made this more clear.

Comment: To all who have responded, thanks for sharing your expertise.  I believe that by stripping the joins from my query for this forum, asking for further assistance from all of you would not be respectful of your time.   And the time i had to work on this today just got derailed.  I will have to revisit when time permits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments:

> I am looking for all Names that have a row with a specific date and a
>   row for the same name with a NULL date

You can do it with EXISTS:

```
select name 
from my_table t
where 
  date = '2019-04-15'
  and exists (
    select 1 from my_table
    where name = t.name and date is null
  )
```

**Edit**
If you want both the row with the non null date and the row with the null date:

```
select t.* 
from my_table t
where ( 
  date = '2019-04-15'
  and exists (
    select 1 from my_table
    where name = t.name and date is null
  )
) or (
  date is null
  and exists (
    select 1 from my_table
    where name = t.name and date = '2019-04-15'
  )  
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d3c229bcbea514044b9e725332db259c)

Comment: I am attempting this.  I just need to figure out how to wrap it in with the joins I have.

Comment: Finally got some time to try these.  I was not aware of the EXISTS clause.  After trying it, I am only getting 4/15 dates, and seems to ignore the NULL conditional.  I have the joins to both select statements.  Both where clauses independently give me their respective filtered results.  But the EXISTS does nothing to modify the results from the first WHERE clause.  I suspect that it has something to do with how I am implementing your solution.  I will keep working with it.

Comment: Try wrapping your query (without my code) inside a CTE and apply my code to the cte, like: `with cte as (<your query>) select distinct name from cte t where   date is not null and exists (select 1 from cte where name = t.name and date is null
  )`

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back to this.  So i wrapped my query in your cte.  The results are a list of unique names with 4/15 date.  Names with a Null are excluded.  (I changed my original posted query to use an AND instead of an OR.)

Comment: So you want also the rows with the pair null value, right?

Comment: I need a list of Names that have both a NULL date a 4/15 date. From the example data in my original post, I would like to see:
`
James   2019-04-15
James   NULL
`
Or just "James" would be acceptable.

Comment: See my edited answer and the the demo at the end. The code does exactly what you mentioned.

Comment: I have to agree with you.  The issue has to be with the way i am translating your use of my_table and my_table t to my query which has joins.   Thanks for the demo.  You clearly have a working solution.  The rest is up to me make it work i my query.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
SELECT a.name
FROM   my_table a
JOIN   my_table b
  ON   a.name = b.name
 AND   b.date IS NULL
WHERE  a.date = '2019-04-15';
```

Of course, if there are multiple records for a specific name with a `NULL` date, you get multiple results.

This could be resolved as follows:

```
SELECT a.name
FROM   my_table a
WHERE  a.date = '2019-04-15'
  AND  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   my_table b
               WHERE  a.name = b.name
                 AND  b.date IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    Date,
    COUNT(C.Date)
FROM my_table AS C

having COUNT(C.Date) > 1
group by
    Name, 
    Date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    Date,
    COUNT(temp.Date)
FROM my_table AS temp
where temp.Date = '2019-04-15' OR temp.Date IS NULL
having COUNT(temp.Date) > 1
group by
    Name, 
    Date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the row which has NULL value as well, you can try below.

```
SELECT m.name,m.Date
FROM   my_table m
WHERE  (m.date = '2019-04-15' OR m.date IS NULL
AND  EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   my_table im
           WHERE  m.name = im.name
             AND  im.date IS NOT NULL))
```

This can also be achieved by using SELF JOIN.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.name,m.Date
FROM   my_table m
INNER JOIN my_table im ON im.Name = m.Name
WHERE  (m.date = '2019-04-15' OR m.date IS NULL
 AND im.Date IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: I tried variations of the EXIST with other answers, but to no avail.  Your is a bit different Yours gives me a list of all names with a NULL date and all names with a date, not unlike just adding a DISTINCT to the first line of the SELECT.   If i understand the EXiSTS clause, it says "Give me Names and the 4/15 records, and now show me the ones in that result are not NULL?"

It's almost like I need to run 2 queries and then a 3rd to match the names found in both.

Comment: Yes it says give me names and dates where date = '2019-04-15' or date is null and then scan table again to see if name matches with the rows selected.